# How can I update the database model after doing a migration in .NET Core 3.1 using Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm new, excuse my ignorance.

I have this class:

```
public class Genre
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [StringLength(40)]
    [Index(IsUnique = true)] //-----------------------> new change
    public string Name{ get; set; }
}
```

In my first migration called `Initial`, I forgot the `[Index(IsUnique = true)]` attribute which makes the `Name` field unique. So now I want to update my database model for this change to take effect.

I installed the package `using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;` to be able to use the `unique` property.

The commands I ran were:

```
EntityFrameworkCore\Add-Migration Initial
EntityFrameworkCore\update-database
```

Apparently I can't do something like:

```
EntityFrameworkCore\Add-Migration change_attribute_name
EntityFrameworkCore\update-database
```

to update the database model and that I updated the `unique` attribute on the `Name` field which is what I am doing.

I would like to update the model of my database, with the new changes. How can I do it? and what is the best way?

**Note**: my SQL Server database has no data yet.

Maybe I've been doing fine, you know why the `unique` attribute is not added in my database model?

(In Spanish Genero=Genre  and Nombre=Name)

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT**

In EF core, you need to apply the unique index in the following way using [Fluent API](https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/efcore/fluent-api-in-entity-framework-core.aspx) in your `ApplicationDbContext.cs` file:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
{
    builder.Entity<Genre>()
        .HasIndex(u => u.Name)
        .IsUnique();
}
```

Since as you mentioned, you **do not have any data in the database** yet, you can revert all your applied migration by using

`Update-Database -Migration 0`

the `-Migration 0` indicates that you want to un-apply all the migrations.

Then you can remove your generated migration using

`Remove-Migration`

And finally, add migration again using new changes by

`Add-Migration Initial`

Comment: maybe i've been doing fine, you know why the `unique` attribute is not added in my database model?

Comment: excuse my ignorance, where do I put this? I don't know what the fluent api is https://i.imgur.com/MWKleZG.jpg

Comment: You put it in your `ApplicationDbContext.cs` file

Comment: thank you very much, it worked. should I do this for every field in every table where I want to put this? I thought there would be a better way to avoid doing this.

Comment: Yes, as of now this is the only way to do it as ASP.NET core does not support annotations for creating indexes

Answer (score 1):

Change the model an try adding migration

Add migration yourmigration name

And then run

Update database

Command this will work for you for sure

Comment: I did that, but in the database I notice that the `unique` attribute is added   `EntityFrameworkCore\Add-Migration Initial
EntityFrameworkCore\update-database `  I added the attribute unique `EntityFrameworkCore\Add-Migration change_atributte_name
EntityFrameworkCore\update-database`